# Integrating Glassfish in Eclipse for Java EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am using Eclipse for Java EE. I have installed Java EE SDK that include Glassfish server. But I do not see Glassfish in the list of servers when creating a web project. How do I add Glassfish to Eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse does indeed not ship with a Glassfish plugin out the box. You need to install it separately. It's quite simple, just click the link *Download additional server adapters* in the *New Server* wizard.

[image]

Wait for the list to be populated and finally pick *Oracle Glassfish Server Tools*.

[image]

After a restart it'll be available among the options.

[image]

*(those screenshots are borrowed from this [JSF 2.0 tutorial on Eclipse + Glassfish](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#IntegrateGlassfishInEclipse))*

Comment: then you'll need to locate your GF path until Eclipse says it is correct

Comment: @Juan: Yes, but that's trivial enough when you click *Next* :)

Comment: As an aside: some (including myself) have had issues with debugging when using the plugin from the Eclipse Market (like: the debugger will stop at breakpoints, but not jump into the actual code), but no problems at all when installing just the server adapter like described above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the eclipse plugin. http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios/

Comment: Please make sure to use http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/helios URL instead. The dlc.sun.com URL is a reference to integration builds of this plugin rather than the released version.

Comment: @ Konstantin Komissarchik
the page is not there, it sayd: We're sorry, the page you requested was not found.

Comment: As an aside: some (including myself) have had issues with debugging (like: the debugger will stop at breakpoints, but not jump into the actual code) when using the plugin, but not when installing just the server adapter [like BalusC explains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626872/integrating-glassfish-in-eclipse-for-java-ee/5626904#5626904).

Answer (score 0):

After installing GlassFish in Eclipse, you can build a complete Java EE 6 application as explained at:

http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/web_app_development_using_java

You can also download Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) which comes with GlassFish pre-bundled.