# How to register existing Glassfish server in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I have previously installed Glassfish and been using it with Netbeans. I have decided to switch to Eclipse. Now, I have installed Eclipse. When creating a new Dynamic Web Project, it does not show Glassfish, so I installed plugins for it but what it does is to install a new Glassfish server.

How will I tell eclipse that I have already a Glassfish server and point it to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a server in the `Preferences---> Server---> Runtime Environments` .

The main point is that you should install `The server adapter for Glassfish` in order to  integrate the glassfish to the eclipse . You can refer  [here](http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/glassfish-integration-in-eclipse-36.html) , and [here](http://server.dzone.com/blogs/arungupta/2008/06/27/glassfish-eclipse-ganymede) for the tutorial.

Comment: its 5pm here. time to go.. but ill look at it and try it tomorrow.. thanks!

Comment: As an aside: some (including myself) have had issues with debugging (like: the debugger will stop at breakpoints, but not jump into the actual code) when using the plugin, but not when installing just the server adapter like suggested above, or [like BalusC explains here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626872/integrating-glassfish-in-eclipse-for-java-ee/5626904#5626904).