# How to register existing Glassfish server and how to change username/password

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I've similar question as in the link, but its didn't resolved my issue. Could someone please advise?

[How to register existing Glassfish server in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187090/how-to-register-existing-glassfish-server-in-eclipse)

I'm new to java and tried installing glassfish in IBM data studio (similar to eclipse) as in the tutorial - http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/glassfish-integration-in-eclipse-36.html
and tried running a JSP file on the server - its showing that the username and password as incorrect. when I was pointing to GlassFish I gave the username as 'admin' and the password also same as 'admin'.

How can i get thru this?

Later, after downloading Java EE and now in Eclipse when I tried downloading glassfish , its not showing up in the 'additional server adapters' list. May be because its already installed. 
Now how can I register this existing glass fish server in Eclipse?

could you please let me know how can I get thru above 2 issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you download Glassfish plugin tools for eclipse? 
Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Find: Glassfish  -> Glassfish tools for [Eclipse Version]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went thru Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed tab and uninstalled 'GlassFish tools for Kepler' and installed it again after searching in FIND box. Now, when I'm trying the run the JSP file RUN AS -> RUN ON SERVER, not sure why GLASSFISH server is not showing up in 'select the server type' list

Comment: Did you add Glassfish server in Eclipse? Open Java ee perspevtice (Window -> Open Perspective -> Java ee), open server tab, right click on it and select new -> server

Comment: Yes, when I tried adding the server, its not showing GLASSFISH in the 'select the server type' list. Its only showing - Apache, Basic, JBoss, ObjectWeb and not the Glassfish

Comment: After installing glassfish tools you shoul have there GlassFish folder. Maybe try restarting eclipse. Also make sure that you have Kepler version of eclipce (since you have downloaded glassfish tools for kepler)

Comment: No Luck. I just restarted Eclipse and its Version: Kepler Service Release 2. Is it possible that I totally uninstall/remove the Glassfish from my system and try installing it again

Comment: For changing the password issue, I right clicked on the glassfish server -> OPEN and removed the password. Now When I run the JSP, its showing the error message as 'Publishing to Glassfish 4.0 at localhost' has encountered the problem and showing the details as Publishing failed
cannot Deploy WebSerTest
deploy is failing=File not found : C:\R. I see that all my files are exiting , not sure why its not getting published

Answer (score 0):

Ensure version of Eclipse installed is the Java EE version. Might be a good idea to un-install GlassFish Tools, restart Eclipse and do the following:

- Go to *Help > Eclipse Marketplace* and search for GlassFish Tools
- Install the version that matches the Eclipse version
- Click *Install*, *Confirm* and then *Accept* the license agreement on the following screens.
- Click *Yes* to restart Eclipse after the installation is complete. You **must restart eclipse** for the remaining steps to work.
- The default layout of the Java EE perspective in eclipse has a Servers tab located in the bottom section. If there are currently no servers, click on text in the content area of the tab to create a new connection to a server. Else, right click in the content are of the tab and select *New > Server*
- There should now be a GlassFish folder in the *Select the server type:* list. Expand the folder and select the relevant version of GlassFish.
- After clicking *next*, select jdk7 as the JDK and browse to the folder where GlassFish is installed. Confirmatory text will be displayed below the last input field if it is found. Click *Next*
- Ensure the correct domain directory is selected (the default is domain1, so it can be $root-glassfish-folder\glassfish\domains\domain1) and enter the Administrator credentials (default Id is ‘admin’, there is no password as the default)
- GlassFish Server should now be present in the Servers view.