# How to add GlassFish Server to Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am using Eclipse Oxygen for Java EE. I have installed the [Java EE 7 Web Profile SDK Update 3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-web-downloads-1956240.html), that includes GlassFish Open Source Edition Web Profile 4.1.2.
When I do File >> New >> Server, the GlassFish does not appear on the server type list.
I already have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626904/3831396) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5626872/3831396), but it didn't help me because in Eclipse Oxygen I don't know where is the option to download additional server adapters.
How can I add GlassFish to Eclipse Oxygen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by just installing GlassFish Tools through Marketplace.

What you have to do is drag the Install button in this link [GlassFish Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools)
and drop in your workspace, it may take a few minutes but after reboot your eclipse you will be able to add a GlassFish server

Comment: as of today that plug in only support glassfish 3 and 4 even though 5 is out.

Comment: GlassFish Tools from the marketplace only supports Neon and lower. Is this an issue for Oxygen users?

Comment: I used glassfish tools from oracle enterprise pack for eclipse. See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Comment: You are right @Hendré There is some issues with glassFIsh Tools from marketplace in eclipse latest versions. I downgraded my eclipse version to use it.